# crontab Operation not permitted - cron has full disk access

Tags: bash, permission, cron

I have seen here various issues about the `crontab` '`Operation not permitted`' issue for Mac OS, but I seem to have a more complex situation on my hands.

I have a bash file on the desktop, which I wanna execute in crontab. Configurations I added:

1. Created the file `untitled.sh` on my Desktop (which has `#!/bin/bash` in the beginning of the file).
2. Ran 'chmod +x untitled.sh'.
3. Using `crontab -e`, added the cron `0 13 * * * /Users/michael/Desktop/untitled.sh`.
4. In Security & Privacy > Privacy, gave Full Disk Permissions to `iTerm`, `Terminal`, `bash` & `cron`.

but I still get the error:

```
/bin/bash: /Users/michael/Desktop/untitled.sh: Operation not permitted
```

What can be done?

Comment: If you run the file in bash, does it work?

Comment: @nohillside yes it does

Comment: Where/how do you get the error?

Comment: after adding the corn job and after it runs, I see the error via the mail command.

Comment: Does anything interesting come up if you view the long list format of the file details with ls -l? I'd be interested to know what the contents of untitled.sh are, and what the results are from a cron job that points to a script containing only the line: #!/bin/bash

Comment: ls -l output:
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 michael staff  1097 Dec  7 22:30 untitled.sh
The contents of the script does not matter, changed it multiple times and it still doesn't run. Also changed it to only include the first row '#!/bin/bash', still no permissions. @Scottmeup

Comment: The @ indicates some extended attributes. Can you check with xattr?

Comment: This file indeed has the extended attr 'com.apple.macl', does this matter? cleaning it with xattr -d doesn't work. @nohillside

Comment: Hmm, are any ACLs set on that file? Can you remove the file and then just run `cat > ~/untitled.sh` and type in your script that way (just the shebang and maybe an echo statement)? And then try again with cron?

Comment: I tried recreating the file (empty/with content) using vim, and it still has this xattr. However when I create it not on the desktop but in $HOME, this attr does not exist and the cron WORKS. So why would it exist by default in Desktop but no in $HOME?

Comment: It looks like mojave, catalina (and possibly later versions of macOS) treat certain folders such as ~/Desktop as special security cases https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/12/18/persistent-file-access-via-com-apple-macl-xattr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting here a partial answer to the question, from the comment section (courtesy to [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside) and [scottmeup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/43053/scottmeup)).

Seems the problem is related to the Extended Attribute `com.apple.macl` that was automatically assigned to the bash file on creation (discovered by running `ls -la FILE_NAME`, and the xattr itself from `xattr FILE_NAME`). This xattr was in fact attached to any file I created on the Desktop, Not sure why; I didn't manage to easily remove it by using `xattr -d`.

When I created the file in e.g. `$HOME`, it didn't have this xattr, and did run in the cron without any additional action. After moving the file from `$HOME` to Desktop, the cron worked as well.